# How to implement a grid overlay on static image with React Native

Tags: css, react-native, grid

I am trying to create a coordinate system for my localisation application. I need a grid of squares that can be individually manipulated by their position. This grid overlay will then be layered on top of a static image.

For example box (1,0) will manipulate the second row first column box.

Here is an example:
[grid overlay on image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5qRN.png)

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, add what did you try so far.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57856509/how-to-make-a-two-column-grid-on-react-native Maybe you can like this :)